# What are some game design YoutTube channels?

Tags: game-design, assets

I already follow quite a few game design channels like [Writing On Games](https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCPlWv88ZRMxCcK3BGjrX7ew) or [Game Maker's Toolkit](https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCqJ-Xo29CKyLTjn6z2XwYAw), and would love to find/follow some more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with game development.

Comment: Hi Toron, unfortunately this question is off-topic, as it's not related to the development of an actual game. You'd find better answers on a discussion-based forum instead.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJfJWct8jN1RpCuVWk3zHTA, https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1JTQBa5QxZCpXrFSkMxmPw, 
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZB6V9fUov0Mx_us3MWWILg, also https://www.youtube.com/user/snomangaming

Comment: But yeah, as @TomTsagk said, this is not quite the place for these kind of questions :D

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be closed. I wanted to ask a question in the style of [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/game-development-blogs) even if it was closed as I thought it would be a nice parallel.

Comment: You have enough reputation to discuss game development video channels and other resources informally on [chat] if you like. There you're not required to use the strict Q&A format, and can just chit-chat about videos you like or topics you'd like to find more about.

Comment: You might want to ask this on a more discussion-oriented community like https://reddit.com/r/gamedev